# How does File.ReadLines(file).Skip(numLines) work?

Tags: c#

I have a rather large file that I wish to read from a particular line. I found

```
File.ReadLines(file).Skip(numLines);
```

which works great. However, I do not understand how this works underneath the surface. I wrote a couple of basic benchmarks to see if there was a performance difference from the way some colleagues had suggested. The methods I tested were:

1. StreamReader used to read through all lines up to that point:

   ```
   public string streamToLine(int lineNumber)
   {
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);

       for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber - 1; i++)
       {
           reader.ReadLine();
       }

       string line = reader.ReadLine();
       reader.Close();

       return line;
   }
   ```
2. File.ReadLines(file) and iterating to the line with an enumerator:

   ```
   public string readToLine(int lineNumber)
   {
       IEnumerator<string> lines = File.ReadLines(fileName).GetEnumerator();
       for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++)
       {
           lines.MoveNext();
       }
       return lines.ToString();
   }
   ```
3. Using the Skip functionality:

   ```
   public string skipToLine(int lineNumber)
   {
       IEnumerator<string> lines = File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(lineNumber-1).GetEnumerator();

       return lines.ToString();
   }
   ```

I ran the tests 10 times over a file with 10 million lines, attempting to read the 9 millionth line and averaged how long this took in milliseconds:

Stream To Line : 2442.1

Read To Line : 2534.9

Skip To Line : 0

It looks like Skip does not even consider the other lines before lineNumber and knows exactly where the 9 millionth line is. Does it somehow infer this from the file? Is there some overhead in the way the other 2 methods process the lines because they are returning what is read? How is there such a big difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, the problem is your test. You haven't called `MoveNext()` on the enumerator, so **it hasn't done anything yet**. Iterators are often deferred and streaming, especially in the case of LINQ.

Incidentally, it is **very** rare that you need to use `GetEnumerator()`; the idiomatic way to access such data is via `foreach`.

If you want to see this in action:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        using(var iter = GetData().GetEnumerator())
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Have iterator");
            while(iter.MoveNext())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(iter.Current);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
    static IEnumerable<int> GetData()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Before doing anything");
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Ater doing everything ");
    }
```

You should notice that `"Have iterator"` is written *before* `"Before doing anything"`, which tells us that one can have an iterator that hasn't done anything yet. It is the first `MoveNext()` that makes it print.

Comment: That was awful oversight on my part. New benchmarks:

Read To Line : 2548.4

Skip To Line : 2509.2

Stream To Line : 2392.9

Comment: Great, thanks for all the additional info and the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the other actually read the line, but the last one does not read the line it self, it just return an enumerable, and enumerable aren't function that run code from line one to 10 and then stop, they work till they reach yield, after that they return control to user, and let user decide that he want to read or not... if you pass, it stop, and if you call it again, it continue from last place it stayed on,...

you some how got me, after i finish writing this answer, as i still my self were worry "how it take zero? this it, seek some how, and bypass", till i refresh and notice of the first answer, tell that you didn't called MoveNext, which i didnt notice, ... and that happen when you convert ienumerable to ienumerator,... enumerable are things that foreach work with, any collection implement it, but enumerator are thing like sql data reader, they move to next item one by one, and you need to check everytime, if there is more item or not, so you didnt get the list, you get the object of class enumerator, which provide methods to read, but it self doesnt do any thing